# Facebook unity webplayer app doesnt load

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine

Our app has been working fine on facebook for some time now but recently the app stopped loading, The app doesnt even start to load now and the loading bar doesnt move at all. The build itself when accessed by its url works just fine but doesnt on facebook.
Here is the facebook link: https://apps.facebook.com/626609470776653/
And the direct url: http://192.30.163.67/Dominos/Web.unity3d
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I tested two links in Chrome browser and both are working fine now. One difference is the direct url required me to enable the plugin with a popup. Please share the reason and solution if you solved this issue.

Comment: It worked fine now, The reason the facebook canvas wasnt loading the game is because The url i gave was an IP which isnt secure but once I gave them the domain instead it worked just fine :)